# OCUnit (SenTestingKit) is deprecated, please convert to XCTest

Tags: objective-c, xml, xcode, parsing, xctest

How can I convert `SenTestingKit` framework to `XCTest`.

My warning is

> SenTestCase_Macros.h:34:2: OCUnit (SenTestingKit) is deprecated,
>   please convert to XCTest.

I am doing XML parsing in Ios (Objective-C)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, the easiest way to, at least, start, would be to :

- delete your test target (keeping your test classes implementation files, of courses).
- create a new test target (in Xcode6+, it is automatically configured to use XCTest)
- put your test class implementation files again inside the new target
- change all your test classes name to XCTestCase
- build and correct the errors/warnings.